# Javascript: "Undefined" is not an object

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am writing a script that deals with a variable `gameRegion` like so:

```
//In the main of the script

var variable= new work();
variable.onCrash(crashHandler,{xPos:650,yPos:300});


// In function work()

var gameRegion;
var onCrashCallback;

this.onCrash = function(crashCallback,fieldSize) {
gameRegion = fieldSize;
onCrashCallback = crashCallback;
};

crashHandler(){
//unimportant
}

this.atBottom = function(ypos) { 
    if(ypos>gameRegion.yPos) //line with the problem
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

I am getting the console error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'gameRegion.yPos')`. Presumably that means I am not properly defining `gameRegion` or its variable `yPos`. I've been looking at this code for a while now and I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Hopefully you'll see something that I don't, but if I'm not including necessary code for context, please tell me. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Be careful -- `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, and not to mention a terrible name for a function object.

Comment: sorry was just using a placeholder, I'll change the name of it for clarification.

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with your code, but it's hard to understand because it's not very usable as posted (you don't even have any sample code that calls the function where you're having the issue). I created a jsfiddle to get my head around it and with a little rearranging it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/wd46G/

Comment: @Cory I'd have to give a lot more context that goes beyond the scope of the question to include `atBottom()`, but the console leads me to believe the the error only resides in declaring and initializing of `gameRegion`, but you're telling me that its correct?

Comment: I'm just saying that in the jsfiddle I posted in the previous comment, your code works (in Chrome). However, context may have a lot to do with why it's not working in your actual code. Would it be possible for you to put just enough code in your own jsfiddle that reproduces the problem so we can study that?

Comment: @Cory Thanks for helping me so far, but if you'd like to spare about more time, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wold/vFH4c/5) is a jsfiddle with more context.

Comment: Good. I think what you are seeing is due to other syntax and programming errors in your JavaScript. Your fiddle doesn't compile or run. I spend about 20 minutes with it cleaning it up, but I started getting too many other errors. If you fix these one by one I think you'll find that your original problem will go away. http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/vFH4c/9/ Compare your version to mine to see what changes I made.

Comment: @Cory Thanks for the help. I'm new to javascript, I was learning a few things as I went along.

Comment: In your code gameRegion is not defined until onCrash is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to handle 'undefined'. Which can be done in these ways:

```
typeof(foo) == 'undefined'
typeof foo !== 'undefined'
window.foo !== undefined
'foo' in window
```

The first three should be equivalent (as long as foo isn't shadowed by a local variable), whereas the last one will return true if the global varible is defined, but not initialized (or explicitly set to undefined).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof) like so -

```
return (typeof (gameRegion) !== "undefined" && 
        typeof(gameRegion.yPos) !== "undefined" &&
        ypos > gameRegion.yPos);
```

Comment: This returns false if gameRegion is undefined and prevents the problem of a console error, but doesn't solve the problem of both of those as being interpreted as undefined (I know they aren't).

Comment: Clearly they are. Do you declare gameRegion anywhere besides your `onCrash` function? And when does `atBottom` get invoked?

Comment: I could try to go into detail explaining atBottom, but then you really need more context and I'd end up having to explain the whole program. I'm sure my problem is with `gameRegion` and no, it is not declared anywhere else.

Comment: `gameRegion` has no value until after `onCrash` is actually invoked.

Comment: Add a console.log in `onCrash` to check; and maybe check the `gameRegion.prototype`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44668/discussion-between-wold-and-elliott-frisch)

Comment: you dont need typeof (x) you can do typeof x